# Unresolved External Symbol. MSVS community 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

When compiling my program, I am getting a link error LINK2019. The common error is that a function was declared but not defined which is not the case here. 
For example I have the class below that is defined in the header file dict.h

```
template<typename key, typename elem>
class Slist{
public:
    list<KV_pair<key, elem>> *data;

    Slist(int size);
    ~Slist();

    void insert(KV_pair<key, elem> &kv);
    elem &operator[](key k_val);
};
```

And I have defined the members as so in a separate dict.cpp file

```
template<typename key, typename elem>
Slist<key, elem>::Slist(int size) {
    data = new list<KV_pair<key, elem>>(size);
}

template<typename key, typename elem>
Slist<key, elem>::~Slist() {


}

template<typename key, typename elem>
void Slist<key, elem>::insert(KV_pair<key, elem> &kv){
    KV_pair<key, elem> *temp;
    for (data->movestart();data->r_len() > 0; data->next()) {
        temp = &data->get_val();
        if (temp->get_key() > kv.get_key()) {
            break;
        }
        data->insert(kv);
    }
}
```

If I put my `main()` in the dict.cpp file everything works, but when I try to put the `main()` in a separate file and `#include "dict.h"` I get the unresolved externals error. Although it is incorrect to do so, using `#include "dict.cpp"`after `#include "dict.h"` resolves the error. I have the dict.h file in the header files directory, and put both the main.cpp and dict.cpp in the source files directory/

Comment: [Why Can templates only be in header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Class declaration and defenition in template case must be in single file.

Comment: Excellent, I was having a bit of a meltdown when this wouldn't work. c++ is definitely a bit of a minefeild of subtleties and pitfalls.

Comment: So the best solution in the link provided advises to make a .tpp file  and include it at the end of the header. What directory should I place the .tpp file?

Comment: @Mykola: Not necessarily, see the question that Ben linked in his comment. Templates can be explicitly instantiated in a .cpp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler expands templated types (and functions) at the point they are used. This means that the compiler must be able to *find* their definition at the point they are used. For this reason all template definitions (not just declarations) must exist in the header, or a file included in the header.